# check this need ,, mysql query 

Tags: mysql

```
table ab:
partyid          conatctpurpose
1                  general
1                  shipping
1                  phone
1                  fax
2                  general
2                  shipping
2                  phone
3                  phone
3                  fax
3                  mail
4                  GENERAL
5                  fax
```

every partyid should be assigned  mandatory 3 contact purposes ( general,shipping,phone ) 
partyid can heve other optional contactpurposes

write a query to return partyid which is not assigned the above mandatory set of contact purposes .

Comment: I don't understand what the list at the beginning of your questions means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@above thank you friends for your support .  finally i got my solution .

-many taught that this is a homework , noob question etc .
-this is a data check report  for our project

(select party_id from (SELECT party_id,count(distinct contact_mech_purpose_type_id) as c FROM party_contact_mech_purpose
 WHERE
contact_mech_purpose_type_id    in
('BILLING_LOCATION','PAYMENT_LOCATION','SHIPPING_LOCATION','SHIP_ORIG_LOCATION')
group by party_id ) t  where c<4)

union

(select party_id from  party_contact_mech_purpose where party_id not in (SELECT party_id FROM party_contact_mech_purpose
 WHERE
contact_mech_purpose_type_id    in
('BILLING_LOCATION','PAYMENT_LOCATION','SHIPPING_LOCATION','SHIP_ORiG_LOCATION')
group by party_id ))

order by party_id

Answer (score 1):

Though NOT IN is not an optimal query, you can use it if your data set is not very large.

```
Select partyid from table_ab where contactpurpose NOT IN ('general','shipping','phone');
```

Comment: hii ,,Thank you for your reply ,, i mean , party id must have compulsory above 3 purposes + other purposes optional . i need to print the partyid which dont have those mandatory 3 purposes

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT partyid
  FROM ab
WHERE   conatctpurpose IN ('general','shipping','phone')
GROUP BY partyid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT conatctpurpose) < 3
```

Comment: hii ,,Thank you for your reply ,, i mean , party id must have compulsory above 3 purposes + other purposes optional . i need to print the partyid which dont have those mandatory 3 purposes

Comment: The query I posted achieves the same.

Comment: hii cybernateee , thank you ,, for your solution .  using your query i find a way to achieve that . please see below for my ans